# Estimate for a shifted cosine

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am considering
$$h(x):=\cos(x-x_0)-1+a,$$
where $a\in (1,2)$ and $x_0\in (0,\pi)$ is chosen uniquely so that $h(0)=0$.

I would like to show that $h(\pi)<-\pi h'(0)$.

To do so, I need that
$$
h(\pi)=\cos(\pi-x_0)-1+a < -\pi h'(0)=\pi\sin(-x_0).
$$

I only get that $0<h(\pi)<h_0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}h(0)=0 &\implies \cos(-x_0)-1+a=0\\&\implies a=1-\cos x_0 \\a\in(1,2)&\implies 1<1-\cos x_0<2 \\&\implies -1<\cos x_0 <0\end{align}$$

Combined with $x_0 \in (0,\pi)$, this implies $x_0 \in (\pi/2, \pi)$.

Now $$\begin{align}\cos (\pi -x_0) - 1 + a < \pi \sin(-x_0) &\iff -\cos x_0-\cos x_0 < -\pi \sin x_0\\&\iff\frac 2 \pi > \tan x_0 \end{align}$$

but for $x_0\in (\pi/2,\pi)$, $\tan x_0 < 0$, so the inequality holds true.

Answer (score 1):

From $h(0)=0$ we get
$$
\cos(0-x_0)-1+a=0\implies a=1-\cos x_0
$$
so that
$$
h(x)=\cos(x-x_0)-\cos x_0
$$
and
$$
h'(x)=-\sin(x-x_0)
$$
In particular
$$
h(\pi)=\cos(\pi-x_0)-\cos x_0=-2\cos x_0\\
h'(0)=-\sin(-x_0)=\sin x_0
$$
The inequality becomes
$$
-2\cos x_0<-\pi\sin x_0\implies \pi\sin x_0-2\cos x_0<0
$$
whose solution is
$$
\arctan (2/\pi)-\pi<x_0<\arctan (2/\pi)
$$